# twig dynamic translation domain

Tags: symfony, twig, translation

I'm trying to translate user content, using a translation domain depending on the role of the user.

here is my code:

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_TEACHER') %}
    {% set translation_domain = 'ROLE_TEACHER' %}
{% else %}
    {% set translation_domain = 'ROLE_PARENT' %}
{% endif %}

<h5>{{"Main Title"|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</h5>
```

This works perfect for a user, in browser.
However the command for generating the translations (bin/console translation:extract en) generates them for the 'undefined' translation domain.

Is there a better way? Any ideas?
Whats the standard way for doing this? I cant seem to find any docs.

Comment: [Translation Docs here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#translations-in-templates) and specifically translation in templates.

Comment: There's no logged in user when executing the command, so the variable is undefined and that behaviour is expected. To have any chance to pull that off you'd have to basically rewrite the [`TranslationExtension`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/b7ce8f23d3854d5417eacefa99af8e20e0841a52/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Translation/TwigExtractor.php#L64) so I don't think is feasible.

Comment: @Bossman where in the docs do you see anything that would help me? i have read the docs, theres nothing helpfull.

Comment: @msg do you have any other aproch that would work? of an aproach that would do something similar?

Comment: If memory serves, even if the `if` block is not evaluated, the extractor is just a regular expression matcher that runs against all nodes so if you move the `trans` call inside the `if`/`else` and don't use a variable it _should_ work. That's to say: `{% if is_granted('ROLE_TEACHER') %} {% set trans_message = 'Main Title' trans({}, 'ROLE_TEACHER') %} {% else %} ...`.